# Searching for a way to replace elements of character vectors in a list

Tags: r, list, lapply

I have a list of character vectors of different length, containing identifiers (e.g. "011" or "12"), numbers indicating the amount of money ("112.3" or "490.5") and years ("2011" or "2020"), empty elements ("") and elements only containing a dot("."). I want to get rid of the elements of character vectors that only contain a dot or are empty. The leading zeros of the identifiers are important, so I cannot change the type to numeric.

This original data

```
l <- list(c("2015","2016"),c(""),c("."), c("0","2418.9","292.4"),c("2",".",".","2394.6"),c("011","","934.0","1200.7"))
```

should look like this:

```
l_final <- list(c("2015","2016"),c("0","2418.9","292.4"),c("2","2394.6"),c("011","934.0","1200.7"))
```

My idea is to create a list with TRUE/FALSE indicating for each vector which elements to keep, but right now I'm really stuck as the following approach does not work (it returns integers that are zero) :

```
test <- lapply(list, function(i) {unlist(lapply(list[i], function(b) which(b==".")))})
```

Regarding the expression for ".", I already tried other regular expressions like "\." and "[.]".

Comment: FYI, its good practice not to assign objects to the global environment the same name as functions that already exist in R - here `list <- list(..)`  -- `list` is already a function in R, so may want to change your data to `list_char <- list(...)` or something else. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could loop over the `list`, subset the elements that are not `.` or `""` and `Filter` out the list elements that are empty

```
Filter(length, lapply(list, function(x) x[! x %in% c(".", "")]))
```

-output

```
[[1]]
[1] "2015" "2016"

[[2]]
[1] "0"      "2418.9" "292.4" 

[[3]]
[1] "2"      "2394.6"
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I only had to substitute <function(x) x[! x %in% c(".", "")])> with function(x) x[grepl(pattern="\\d\\.*\\d",x)==TRUE]), as for some reason in my original list empty elements are not really empty.

Comment: @SusannaB probably you had spaces `" "`,  then it may need `trimws(x) %in% c(".", "")`

Answer (score 2):

A two-step solution doubling down on `lapply`, if needed/as an alternative:

```
# data
l <- list(c("2015","2016"),c(""),c("."), c("0","2418.9","292.4"),c("2",".",".","2394.6"))

# remove those with "." or ""
l2 <- lapply(l, function(x) {x[!(x %in% c(".", ""))]})

# remove empty list positions
l2[lapply(l2, length) > 0]

#[[1]]
#[1] "2015" "2016"

#[[2]]
#[1] "0"      "2418.9" "292.4" 

#[[3]]
#[1] "2"      "2394.6"
```